# Is there a "null" value for std::thread::id?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'd like to have a class member of type `std::thread::id` where I can also nullify it and then check whether it has been set.

What is the best way to "nullify" this type and then check whether it has been set?

Comment: `boost::optional<std::thread::id>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [cppreference on std::thread::id (default constructor)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/get_id):

> Default-constructs a new thread identifier. The identifier does not represent a thread.

So, you can store and compare against a default constructed `std::thread::id`.

Comment: I think it's worth noting, that it works because the `operator==` for ids is defined this way (*Returns: true only if x and y represent the same thread of execution or neither x nor y represents a thread of execution.*).
Also - the `t.get_id() == id()` is true in some states of the thread `t`.